# Identical immutable tuples point to different objects

Tags: python, object, immutability

I understand that python will economize with certain immutable types by pointing to the same object in memory for two equivalent objects. Such as declaring variables to the same number (within the bounds of -5 and 256):

```
i = 5
j = 5
i is j
>> True
```

...and sets:

```
tuple1 = ()
tuple2 = ()
tuple1 == tuple2
>> True
tuple1 is tuple2
>> True
```

Because sets (immutable type) can contain mutable types such as lists that can be modified, I understand that Python wouldn't want to point to the same object as in the case:

```
tuple3 = ([1, 2, 3], a, b)
tuple4 = ([1, 2, 3], a, b)
tuple3 is tuple4
>> False
```

...How come the following tuples don't point to the same object as they are both, according to my knowledge, immutable under all conditions?

```
tuple5 = ((),())
tuple6 = ((),())
tuple5 == tuple6
>> True
tuple5 is tuple6
>> False
```

Comment: It is usually a fool's errand to search for reasons why a particular implementation was done a certain way, especially when it is emphasized that the details may vary in time and in implementation, as is the case here. We don't have access to the programmers meetings where such decisions are made, and the making of the sausage is not always pretty.

Comment: You are talking about tuples, not sets.

Answer (score 0):

The pointers are folded when, in the opinion of the Python engine, the object is simple enough to warrant entry in the run-time table of simple constants.  This table often includes small integers (such as -256 through 255), empty/null objects of built-in types, and similar trivialities.

More complex objects -- as defined by those who designed the Python implementation -- are rebuilt at each reference.  Thus, you might find that

```
a = 1
b = 1
```

Refer to the same object, but

```
a = 123456798
b = 123456798
```

Have separate allocations.

Comment: That would be *-5 through 256* in CPython.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm familiar with how Python optimizes for integers; however, certain rules for immutable types pointing to objects still confuse me. I do understand that the creators of Python can't account for every specific case, as Mr Rory Daulton aptly noted.

Comment: Can you describe / delimit what still confuses you?  Rory's main point (also mine) is that there really are *not* Python rules for which constants get special treatment -- that decision is left to those who implement Python.